# JQuery UI calendar dialog not closing on selection with an onchange event on the date control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a few date controls in my application and have added a JQuery UI calendar control as a dialog image selector:

```
<input type="text" id="punchStartDate" class="EndDateClass" name="punchStartDate" />
```

Here is how I am adding the calendar control:

```
 jQuery("input.EndDateClass").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "../images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: dateFormat.replace("DD", "dd").replace("D", "d").replace("MM", "mm").replace("M", "m").replace("yyyy", "yy"),
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            if (jQuery(this).is(':disabled')) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

This works fine, but I have a few controls that I have also added an onchange event.  With these, the calendar controls still shows and populates the input, but the dialog *does not disappear once a date is selected*.  This only happens periodically, so I am suspecting a race condition.

Here is the input that causes this:

```
<input type="text" id="punchStartDate" class="EndDateClass" name="punchStartDate" onchange="CheckWeekdays.SetCheckBoxes('punch');" />
```

I suspect that the onchange event is blocking the hide event of the dialog, but not sure how to fix this.  How to correct this race condition between competing javascript calls?

Comment: it might be an error in this function CheckWeekdays.SetCheckBoxes('punch');

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to Sam, there was an error in the onchange function *since it relied on the start and end dates*.  I didn't write the function so didn't realize they might be connected.  My bad for assuming the race condition, thanks again for helping me out!